# Transparency in app icon for Mac App Store

Tags: macos, mac-app-store

I'm tried to submit my first Mac App Store app (I already have a few iOS ones), but I'm having some problems with the app icon.

On iOS, the icon needs to be a square without transparency and the OS will do its magic to make it look like it should.
On the other hand, on Mac, icons are not square, so I submitted an app with with an icon in all the right sizes (all pngs with some alpha).

Unfortunately, the preview seems to have replaced the semi-transparent areas with black pixels. See [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8mGx.png).

In the screenshot, you can see that app icon in "included assets" is fine (it's a bit blurry, I think because it's scaling down a high-res image), but the App Store Icon is ugly.

What am I supposed to do about this? Will the icon actually look like that on the Mac App Store?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I decided to just try and publish the app. It's now in the app store and the icon looks fine with the right transparency.

I wonder if this bug is just a sign of Apple paying less attention to details for the Mac App Store compared to the iOS one!